# MySQL FullText Searching Exact Phrases with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search, prepared-statement

How do you match exact phrases in full text searches when using prepared statements?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT (IF(MATCH(title) AGAINST(:search_exact)>0, 10, 0) AS Score FROM table");
$stmt->execute(array("search_exact"=>"the full title"));
```

That query will return anything that has the words "full" or "title" in the title, but what if I want to search for "the full title"?